# Django custom ManyToMany fields don't show up in the Admin

Tags: django

All my ManyToMany show up in my Admin form, except the custom ones while using `through`;

**Original Model fields**

```
class Action(models.Model):
    combo_action = models.ForeignKey('Action', related_name = '+', blank = True, null = True, through = 'Action_Effects')
    combo_bonus_effects = models.ManyToManyField('Effect', related_name = 'ComboInflicted', through = 'Action_Combo_Effects')
```

**Reference Models**

```
class Action_Effects(models.Model):

    action = models.ForeignKey('Action')
    effect = models.ForeignKey('Effect')
    duration = models.IntegerField(blank = True, null = True)
    combo_potency = models.IntegerField(blank = True, null = True)

class Action_Combo_Effects(models.Model):

    action = models.ForeignKey('Action')
    effect = models.ForeignKey('Effect')
    duration = models.IntegerField(blank = True, null = True)
    combo_potency = models.IntegerField(blank = True, null = True)
```

I can't find a way to display these still.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django Admin: Many-to-Many listbox doesn't show up with a through parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854350/django-admin-many-to-many-listbox-doesnt-show-up-with-a-through-parameter)

Comment: I met same problem, and action.combo_bonus_effects don't have add() function. In default ManyToManyField way, you can use add() to add a related object.